# How to open a report based on records shown in split form

Tags: forms, split, report

I have made a split form and in that split form I have made a text box and a command button so when I search for a specific record it is showed in the Split form.

My problem is that I want to open a report with the records that is showed in the split form but when I creat the macro Open Report and bound it to another command button, it show all the records from my table.

I think need to write someting in the Where conditions and I have tried alot but I cant get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You are right you have to write specific select query for getting result.
Query below will help you.

SELECT * FROM your_TableName WHERE your_ColumnName LIKE 's%';